# How to push to new View with programatically created UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I try many sings from this site but not get result. Now I open new View like this:

```
//(I call this code from View called MainReportView)
InfoController *info = (InfoController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoController"];

info.login = login;
info.password = password;

[self presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];
```

all working good, but I want previous View be in the same state when I return to him. People say use NavigationController and push to him but this is a problem. I add NavigationController to storyboard (to MainReportView) and try change code to:

```
 [self pushViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but nothing happens, view not open, please help how I can programatically in this code add NavigationController and open my InfoController with push ? Thanks ! (I use Xcode 5 and iOS 7 + Storyboard)

Solution - for iOS7 use prepareForSegue, and this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

Comment: try this `[self.NavigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: [self.navigationcontroller pushViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: If you using storyBoard then Do, 'Perform segue With Identifier' Other Wise Upper Commemnts Useful for you. I want To add That If you using XIB then do, 'Self.NavigationController PushViewControllerWithNibName:YorXibName'.

Comment: did you check that info != nil? is info a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: yes, you should use a UINavigationController

Comment: Sorry but I newbie in iOS programming and not understand what to do.

Comment: You have two controllers or views?

Comment: Now all working, first my problem Navigation Controller be on in the start of application and if I use storyboard I don't use prepareForSegue. And because I new in iOS programming I create Navigaton controller for all views  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
UIStoryboard *MainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
InfoController *info=[MainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[full step by step guide](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Comment: I do the same but not working ( What I have in storyboard - [storyboard screenshot](http://imgur.com/ziKjDSI)

Comment: please do attach screenshot in question.

Comment: I cannot add screenshots, I registered today.

Comment: InfoController *info = (InfoController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoController"]; [self presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil]; This code is working good. But I need push.

Comment: for pushing view controlller... [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I select my view controller and in Xcode menu use Editor - Embed In - Navigation controller, after this I Click left on my view controller and drug mouse from push to my Infoview controller, on the menu be only Custom I select it. What I have after this you can look on screenshot link upper. Thanks.

Comment: In my MainReportView I see this comment - #pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
} maybe I need use it ?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/ follow this great tutorial.

Comment: All work, thanks, main - Navigation controller must be firs at start of your application. I try use it at next views.

Comment: Only accept because I don't have reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Push the new view controller in the navigation controller like this:

```
InfoController *info = (InfoController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];
```